# Oracle update based on query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got the folloing tables:rashodz, naklrashodz, transport, trans_task_load, shipment_plan.
 What I need is to update tbl:rashodz.id_ship whith tbl:shipment_plan.id_ship  as follows

```
rashodz.id2 = shipment_plan.id2
and rashodz.nsthet = naklrashodz.nsthet  
and naklrashodz.nsthet = trans_task_load.nsthet    
and shipment_plan.idts = trans_task_load.idts
```

Just do not have an idea how to do it.
When there are two tables under consideration there is no problem, but how to do it when multiple   tables are involved? 
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the code snippet you give the condition for the update?

Then how about:

```
update rashodz r
set id_ship = nvl(
                   (select id_ship
                   from shipment_plan, 
                        naklrashodz, 
                        transport, 
                        trans_task_load
                   where r.id2 = shipment_plan.id2
                       and r.nsthet = naklrashod.nsthet  
                       and naklrashod.nsthet = trans_task_load.nsthet    
                       and shipment_plan.idts = trans_task_load.idts
                   ), id_ship)
```

The purpose of the NVL in this case is that if there is no match, id_ship remains unchanged from its original value.

Comment: I tried this way, but it returns an error message that single row query returns more than one row.

Comment: By the way, in the code snippet there is the join condition. I can upload DDLs for the tables, if it can help. I am just frastrated.

Comment: What Mike has given you there is a good answer, however, you have not given us enough information to give you a final answer. If you are getting the "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" then there is obviously some information that you have not given that is needed for a working query. Post the additional info and we can give you more help.

Comment: In your table structure, is it possible to have several id_ship in shipment_plan that match one single id_ship in rashodz?

Comment: The point is that rashodz.id_ship is empty now. And shipment_plan.id_ship can only match one single rashodz.id_ship.

Comment: CREATE TABLE rashodz
 (
  nsthet                     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  idr                        NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  idk1                       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
  id1                        NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  id2                        NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
  kol                        NUMBER(14,6),
  cenaprodr_r                NUMBER(14,6),
  note                       VARCHAR2(20),
  idshipment                 NUMBER(10),
  id_ship                    NUMBER(10)
 )

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `CREATE TABLE shipment_plan
 (
  id_ship                    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  idorder                    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  supply_date                DATE NOT NULL,
  ship_date                  DATE,
  ship_time                  DATE,
  ordered_qty                NUMBER NOT NULL,
  id_adres                   NUMBER(10),
  idk1                       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
  id2                        NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
  idts                       NUMBER,
  ship_order                 NUMBER(2)
 )`

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `CREATE TABLE naklrashodz
 (
  nsthet                     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  data                       DATE,
  id_pok                     NUMBER(10),
  id_prod                    NUMBER(5),
  idfio                      NUMBER(10),
  id_d                       NUMBER(10),
  printkomplect              NUMBER(1),
  note                       VARCHAR2(600),
  finish                     NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
  idk                        NUMBER(10),
  id_pok2                    NUMBER(10),
  printzero                  NUMBER(1)`

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `CREATE TABLE transport
 (
  idts                       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
  datets                     DATE NOT NULL,
  dtconfirm                  NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  tmship                     DATE,
  printkomplect              NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
  printzero                  NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0,
  id_dr                      NUMBER
 )`.

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `CREATE TABLE trans_task_load
 (
  nsthet                     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  idts                       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
 )`.

Comment: Those above are DDLs for the tables involved. The point is that the DB structure changed a bit. So I need to update the table rashodz with shipment_plan.id_ship. Shipment_plan is the order for dispatch of goods. In each row there is single id2, which is identificator of goods to be dispatched. In Naklrashodz (invoice) I store the general invoice data, like date, customer id. In rashodz I store data about goods to be invoiced. Transtaskload links Transport (delivery data) and Naklrashodz. So I need to update rashodz with id_ship, to know for which dispatch this invoice is. Thanks in advance.